# LocationManager in TabbarViewContoller can not trigger didUpdateLocations when app was terminated (Background location)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, cllocationmanager

I want to use `locationManager` in one of my ViewControllers, which is in a tab bar. When the app is in the **Foreground** or in the **background** `didUpdateLocations` is triggered fine, but when user the kills the app, `didUpdateLocations` Is not triggered.

I found that when I move my code to a single `ViewContoller`, `didUpdateLocations` Is triggered fine.

Does anyone have idea how to fix this without using the locationManager in the AppDelegate?

Comment: A view controller is probably the wrong place since the view controller will not be instantiated when the app is relaunched in the background. You should probably have it in its own class that is instantiated from the App Delegate.

Comment: U mean create singleton class and use in appDelegate and any ViewContollers ?

Comment: Yes,  I would typically have a single object to be the location manager delegate and have that object issue `NSNotification` for updates to other interested objects.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thanks for your help

Comment: @Paulw11 I've create new class with singleton when use startLocationUpdate in ViewController in kill state didUpdateLocations is not triggered. when use startLocationUpdate in AppDelegate, in kill state didUpdateLocations is triggered fine. why ? my class is singleton

Comment: Because your view controller won't be instantiated in that case; you can't rely on any code in it.